# Dictionary<Type,Object> vs Dictionary<RuntimeTypeHandle,Object> what's more performance wise?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

What is consider more performance wise? hashing a `RuntimeTypeHandle` or hashing a `Type`? please try to explain why.

Comment: Have you tried it both ways and compared them?  What makes you think there sill be a significant performance impact?  Is this a bottleneck inn a particular application or are you just curious?

Comment: Just curious, I took C# course a while ago and he told us that RuntimeTypeHandle is more performance wise for hashing. I don't really know how to check them because I need many types, it won't do much work if I'll hash 10 types.

Comment: Well, you could search for keys a million times each way and see if there's a difference.  Dictionary access is `O(1) ` so the size of the dictionary doesn't have much (if any) bearing on the performance.  The speed and distribution of your hashing algorithm makes all the difference.

Comment: Well, I did what you say and apparently its faster to hash Type and not RuntimeTypeHandle. So I did another benchmark and since `GetType` and `typeof` returns the same `Type` object everytime, I tried to find value by `GetType().GetHashCode()` vs `GetType()`. It seems to be much faster to hash the hash code (int32) then to use the Type itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *any* question of "whihc is faster" the only definitive way to answer is to try the same thing different ways and compare the results.  That may mean doing it a million times to get a significant difference, but anything else is academic.

That said, the main differentiator in the performance of dictionaries is their key types, specifically the performance and distribution of their hashing algorithm.

Looking at the source code for [`RuntimeTypeHandle.GetHashCode`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/d172dea31373dab6.html), you can see that it uses the hash code of the underlying `RuntimeType` instance.

```
    private RuntimeType m_type;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return m_type != null ? m_type.GetHashCode() : 0;
    }
```

Now `RuntimeType` does not override `GetHashCode`, so it much come from it's inherited type, `TypeInfo`.  `TypeInfo` *also* does not override `GetHashCode`, so it uses *its* inherited type, which is `Type`!

So since the `GetHashCode` implementation for `RuntimeTypeHandle` is the same as `Type`, I would not expect a *significant* performance difference.

Comment: Thanks, I did some benchmarks you can see my comment above. It has a minor difference but it seems that you're right. it faster to hash `Type` then `RuntimeTypeHandle`.